# Ongoing For Loop - Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a `dictionary`, with file-/directory paths in it. In the for loop, I do check if the path links to a file or a directory. If it is a directory I have to do the loop again, but one level deeper.

I have to do this until I no longer have any dir paths in the dict.
I do not know how many levels a dir has and I do not want to make redundant code in it.

Can anybody help me?

Example:

```
# here i do have the top level for loop
for each_path in file_or_dir_paths.keys():
    # then i check if the path links to a dir
    # in dictionary[each_path] the date of the file/dir is stored
    # but this isnt important yet
    status = is_it_dir(each_path, dictionary[each_path])
    # status 0 means an empty dir
    if status == 0:
        del dictionary[each_path]
    # status 1 means a dir with files in it
    if status == 1:
        # and here i do have to do the loop again
        # which is redundant and will get deeper with every loop iteration
        dictionary[each_path] = for_loop_again
    # status 10 means path is a file
    if status == 10:
        # this section is not important right now
        dictionary[each_path] = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to use Python's buildin function `walk()`, to traverse the directory structure. `walk()` will visit all subdirs at any depth. Here's how you can use it.

```
from os import walk

# assume variable root contain your root path

for path, dirs, files in walk(root):
   # do what you need to do with the files and dirs
```

If you want to write your own traversal code for some reason, then you would need to use recursion, you cannot have a fixed amount of nested loops (as you seem to suggest)